# Diffraction of sound waves vs EM waves

Tags: electromagnetism, acoustics, diffraction

How does the diffraction of sound waves differ from the diffraction of EM waves?

EM waves have their electric field vector point in a direction perpendicular to the direction of travel and sound waves do not. But how does this impact diffraction?

Answer (score 2):

it does not change the diffraction, but there are numerous articles about sound diffraction f.ex https://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/sound/Lesson-3/Reflection,-Refraction,-and-Diffraction

Comment: This is very confusing to me still as I haven't seen an actual derivation of diffraction, such a proof would seem like it would need to take into account the direction of the field